# Check if the goal has been achieved

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a character and a target where it should go. If the target is in other coordinates, then the character moves towards it, when he reach it, then the walk animation is turned off.

I have 2 problems:

1. When the target is moved and the character reaches it, the coordinates of the target and the character are a little different.
2. Target (GameObject plane) after moving has strange Y-meanings. How to make Y always equal to 0.

The screenshot shows that the character has reached the goal, but the animation does not end because their coordinates are slightly different.

[image: Screenshot]

Move

```
transform.rotation = Target.transform.rotation;
var direction = (Target.transform.position - transform.position).normalized;
_characterController.Move(direction * WalkSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
```

Target

```
if (DistanceToPlayer >= MaxDistanceToPlayer)
{
    if(isMove == false)
    {
        isMove = true;
        Vector3 NewPositionToPlayer = Player.transform.position + new Vector3 (Random.Range(-5.0f, 5.0f), 0f, Random.Range(-5.0f, 5.0f));
        Target.transform.position = NewPositionToPlayer;
        
        animator.SetBool("isWalking", true);
    }
}

if (DistanceToPlayerPivot >= MaxDistanceToPlayer)
{
    isMove = false;
}

if(RelativePosition == Target.position)
{
    animator.SetBool("isWalking", false);
    isMove = false;
}
```

Comment: Always remember that in the real world real numbers are never equal. It's only when we round, approximate, or compare to a confidence interval that we can get equality. Floating point numbers seductively offer the `==` operator to lull us into a false sense that equality exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of comparing `RelativePosition` to `Target.position` compare `RelativePosition` to a small area surrounding `Target.position` - use the size of the target to determine the size of the area.

Comparisons:

1. If  the x-axis of `RelativePosition` is greater than the x-axis of (`Target.position` - (width of the target / 2)) AND the x-axis of `RelativePosition` is less than the x-axis of (`Target.position` + (width of the target / 2))
2. If  the y-axis of `RelativePosition` is greater than the y-axis of (`Target.position` - (height of the target / 2)) AND the y-axis of `RelativePosition` is less than the y-axis of (`Target.position` + (height of the target / 2))

If you did both of those comparisons and they were both true then the character should be within the target.